# grid filter in dojo

Tags: dojo, grid, dojox.grid.datagrid

can any one help with filtering multiple condition in dojo grid.
im using grid.DataGrid and json data.
    data1 = {items: [ {"id":1,"media":"PRINT",pt:"Yellow Directory"},
    {"id":2,"media":"DIGITAL",pt:"Social Media"},{id":3,"media":"DIGITAL",pt:"Yellow Online"}
    ],identifier: "id"};

```
a=1,b=2;
grid.filter({id:a,id:b})
```

the above line is just displaying the record with b value.
i need the record with both the values.
can any one help me with this.???

Answer (score 0):

So you want the records that have any of the specified ids?

It comes down to the capabilities of the store you're using.  If you're using a Memory store with SimpleQueryEngine, then you can specify a regex or an object with a test function instead:

```
grid.filter({id: {
  test: function(x) {
    return x === 'a' || x === 'b';
  }
}});
```

If you're using JsonRest store, then you get to choose how your queries are processed server-side so you could potentially pass in an array of interesting values and handle that in your own way on the server. (i.e. `filter({id:[a,b]})`)

Comment: grid.filter({id:new RegExp(a+"|"+b)},true);

Comment: So use a filter specifying either a custom filter test function or a custom regexp.  Either way, the answer I gave above will allow you to completely customise what you filter on.